# Symfony Easyadminbundle disabling theme selector

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, styling, symfony2-easyadmin

I'm currently working on an application using the easyadminbundle, and I'm adding custom color pallets. For product requirements, the option to select the dark mode should be disabled/hidden, so the user is always in light mode

[image: image of color selector]

I tried to disable the option through css/js fiddling, but configuration of easyadminbundle would be way cleaner

I was hoping there is a configuration option to disable the option to change it, anyone has any suggestions?

Easyadminbundle 4.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You enable/disable the darkmode in the DashboardController by  overriding the configureDashboard method and calling disableDarkMode:
https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/dashboards.html